# Using two github accounts on the same computer with https

Tags: git, github

How can I use two github accounts on the same computer without using SSH keys? I go to school in a district that blocks all SSH traffic and would like to be able to work on projects at school on my personal laptop without having to hotspot to my phone.

edit: I am trying to get the same functionality that I would get if I used ssh keys to authenticate based on which folder the repository was in on my computer

more edit: I am a noob and prefer to use github desktop

Comment: Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: What's the issue, just switch the remote to https https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https and authenticate with your username/password

Comment: See new edits, I am trying to not have to login and out to switch accounts